# Limit problem: $\lim\limits_{n\to ∞} \sqrt[n]{7^n+3^n}$

Tags: limits

$$\lim_{n\to ∞} \sqrt[n]{7^n+3^n}$$

The answer should be $7$, but I have no idea how to get there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Factor out the biggest term:
$$L = \lim_{n \to +\infty} \sqrt[n]{7^n\left(1 + \left(\frac37\right)^n\right)} = \lim_{n \to +\infty} 7\sqrt[n]{1 + \left(\frac37\right)^n} = 7,$$
since $3/7 < 1$ and $(3/7)^n \to 0$.

You can easily generalize the above to prove:
$$\lim_{n \to +\infty} \left(a_0^n + \cdots + a_k^n\right)^{1/n} = \max\{a_0, \ldots, a_k\},$$
with $a_0,\ldots,a_k \in \mathbb R^+$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! You've really helped me out.  =]

Comment: @DanielK Happy to have been of help!

Answer (score 4):

HINT:

$$7^n<7^n+3^n<2\cdot7^n$$

Now employ [Squeeze theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem)

Answer (score 2):

Note $\forall c>0$,$\lim\sqrt[n]{c}=1$

Hence $\sqrt[n]{7^n+3^n}=7\sqrt[n]{1+\frac{3}{7}^n}$, while $1\le \sqrt[n]{1+\frac{3}{7}^n}\le \sqrt[n]{2}$, then use squeeze theorem.

Answer (score -1):

$$\lim_{n\to +\infty}\sqrt[n]{7^n+3^n}$$
$$=\lim_{n\to +\infty}\left(7^n+3^n\right)^{1/n}$$
$$=\lim_{n\to +\infty}7\left(1+\frac{3^n}{7^n}\right)^{1/n}$$
$$=7\lim_{n\to +\infty}\left(1+\left(\frac37\right)^n\right)^{1/n}$$

since, $\frac 37<1\implies $ $\lim_{n\to +\infty}\left(\frac 37\right)^n=0$, 
$$=7\left(1+0\right)^{0}=\color{red}{7}$$

Answer (score -1):

$$
\sqrt[n]{7^n+3^n}=7\left(1+\frac{1}{(7/3)^n}\right)^n \to 7\lim_n e^{n/(7/3)^n}=7.
$$

Comment: I'm confused by the sudden transition from an $n$th root to an $n$ power in the first of the chain equations.

Comment: I think this answer can be improved with more actual words. Some explanation, like writing your $7^n+3^n$ as $7^n(1+\frac{3^n}{7^n})$ and stating that you "factorised out $7^n$" would help.